# Sentry Login using username or email (any of em) in Laravel 4

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

Currently I am using sentry login using email , I know how easily it can be converted into username if I simply change the

sentry config file to this

```
'login_attribute' => 'username',
```

But I find it odd because then the emailing of forget password info became unreachable. What I want is, I want to give user the freedom to choose the artibute as username or email any of them, during the login ....

Any idea How to start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

Locate the user using whatever login field your user choose:

```
$user = User::where(Input::get('login_field'), Input::get('login_name'))->first();
```

Create valid credentials using the e-mail of the user you just found:

```
$credentials = array(
    'email'    => $user ? $user->email : null,
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
);
```

And authenticate it:

```
$user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
```

Comment: Yes this is a good logic actually ! Thank you ! But in this case still the find user by login can not be done with username and there also I need to search the corresponding field by where clause. But it seems that this is the only way at this moment.  bencorlett was saying things going to be changed in v3 of sentry [here](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/180#issuecomment-29557143) AND [HERE](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/pull/317)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in the database user table, you should add username field into it.

In your login function, you can do following to verify account by username or email:

```
$username = Input::get('username');
$password = Input::get('password');

$field = filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';

try {
    if (empty($username)) {
        throw new Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException();
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        throw new Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException();
    }

    $user = User::where($field, '=', $username)
        ->first();

    if (empty($user)) {
        throw new Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException();
    }

    if (!Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
        throw new Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\WrongPasswordException();
    }

    // Authenticate the user
    Sentry::login($user, $remember);
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException $e) {
    ...
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException $e) {
    ...
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\WrongPasswordException $e) {
    ...
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e) {
    ...
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotActivatedException $e) {
    ...
}
```

With this way, we only access to database one time for user information.

Hope this help.